# how to understand the observable function under createStore

Tags: redux

I am reading the source code of redux.

anyone could help me understand the the function under createStore here?

It seems it implemented another version of observer pattern.

questions:

I didn't found any codes called this function, why the code appears here. what is the purpose?
2. how to call this function by store (the key is generated by Symbole ($$observable))

```
function observable() {
var _ref;

var outerSubscribe = subscribe;
return _ref = {
  /**
   * The minimal observable subscription method.
   * @param {Object} observer Any object that can be used as an observer.
   * The observer object should have a `next` method.
   * @returns {subscription} An object with an `unsubscribe` method that can
   * be used to unsubscribe the observable from the store, and prevent    further
   * emission of values from the observable.
   */

  subscribe: function subscribe(observer) {
    if (typeof observer !== 'object') {
      throw new TypeError('Expected the observer to be an object.');
    }

    function observeState() {
      if (observer.next) {
        observer.next(getState());
      }
    }

    observeState();
    var unsubscribe = outerSubscribe(observeState);
    return { unsubscribe: unsubscribe };
  }
}, _ref[$$observable] = function () {
  return this;
}, _ref;
}

// When a store is created, an "INIT" action is dispatched so that every
// reducer returns their initial state. This effectively populates
// the initial state tree.
dispatch({ type: ActionTypes.INIT });

return _ref2 = {
dispatch: dispatch,
subscribe: subscribe,
getState: getState,
replaceReducer: replaceReducer
 }, _ref2[$$observable] = observable, _ref2;
}
```

fake code:

we need something like

```
 var store$= store[$$observable]()
```

to get the observable.
and anyone want to be notified when state changed, need to do

store$.subscribe(observer);

but now. I can't get the  store[$$observable]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a few test:

`var x = window.Symbol.for('observable');
    var y = store[x];
    var z = y();
    console.log(x);
    console.log(store[x]);
    console.log("y", y);
    console.log("z", z);`

do not make the breakpoint to see the runtime value. undefined sometimes.
but you can use it actually.

log:

```
Symbol(observable)
main.tsx:138 observable() {
var _ref;

var outerSubscribe = subscribe;
return _ref = {
  /**
   * The minimal observable subscription method.
   * @param {Object} observer Any obje…
main.tsx:139 y observable() {
var _ref;

var outerSubscribe = subscribe;
return _ref = {
  /**
   * The minimal observable subscription method.
   * @param {Object} observer Any obje…
main.tsx:140 z Object {}subscribe: subscribe(observer)Symbol(observable): ()__proto__: Object
```